# Is there any web application that can be used for doing simple office desk layouting?

Tags: office-online

I am looking for a simple web application, preferably free and that can be used to edit and share a simple office/desk plan?

The entire point is to be able to put names and pictures for people in the office.

Some people are using Visio or even Excel to to things like this, but I an looking for a web solution.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Gliffy](http://www.gliffy.com/examples/).

> Draw custom, professional-looking floorplans easily with Gliffy free floor plan design software. A library of shapes makes it easy to drag and drop furniture, appliances, plants, and more wherever you need them.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Sketchup](http://sketchup.google.com/). You can [download it here](http://sketchup.google.com/download/) and it’s free.

Comment: The OP is looking for a web application, not a desktop one. Is there a web version of Sketchup? (Besides Building Maker, that is used for Google Maps.)